# Using Bag in Java

Tags: java, compile-time, bag

[Here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-2.1.1/org/apache/commons/collections/Bag.html), I see that `Bag` class should be in `java.util.Collection` but when I try to use it, I get `cannot be resolved to a type` error.

Should I copy+pase [this](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/13stacks/Bag.java.html) or is there some library missing?

Comment: Your first link show that it is in the org.apache.commons.collections package. Apache commons is an external library and not part of the JDK.

Comment: Isn't there a implementation of a collection, which will solve your problem? What is special at the Bag-class?

Comment: You probably want Guava Multiset since it plays nicer with the JDK Collection's

Comment: The classes have a different behavior and a different API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are 2 different classes neither of which are part of the JDK. One is a [custom class](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/13stacks/Bag.java) that needs to be added to the build path whereas the other is part of the Apache Commons library which need to be added to the classpath.